# Roscpp data time value

Tags: ros

I am working in roscpp and publishing odometry data to a ros node. Two classes are responsible for publishing this data. For safety reasons, it is sometimes necessary to call the destructor on the primary class and post still data (an odometry pose that uses the same values to let ros know the robot is standing still) from the other class. I have already confirmed the secondary class posts the correct pose on the correct anchor.

Most of the time after the switch to the secondary class, I am running into a check failed stemming from the data time not being greater than the previous data's time.

The error message I get is this:

```
F0402 08:12:25.187301  9044 map_by_time.h:43] Check failed: data.time > std::prev(trajectory.end())->first (636898039451158060 vs. 636898039451158060)
```

As you can see it thinks the data time is equal to the previous data time. I have confirmed that the timestamp being published from my code is in the area of `1554227809034068` (in microseconds since epoch), which is accurate to the time I collected the data. After the switch the time stamp is still correct, a value close to and slightly higher than the previous value.

I am trying to figure out why this error message has such a large number for time, and why it does not match the posted timestamp.

Comment: Is all the code running on the same computer or are you operating over a network?

Comment: Its all on the same computer.

Comment: Can you share an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve